# Numpy slicing with container (e.g. tuple or list)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to slice a **nD** `numpy.ndarray`. Assume that it is **3D**  for the sake of simplicity (but in fact it could have been **4D**, **5D**, etc.) and is composed by `nx`, `ny`, `nz` dimensions.

I would like to extract all `nx` rows for a given point `ny`, `nz`, using a container (e.g. a tuple or list) to select `ny` and `nz`.

### Example:

Say I have a **3D** array `X` of dimension: (46841, 128, 20), and I have a `container = (127,11)`

Desired solution:

`x_selected = X[:,container]`

where `x_selected` should have dimensions (46841,)

Comment: Don't you do just `x_selected = X[:, 127, 11]` or in other words `x_selected = X[:, container[0], container[1]]`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The issue with this approach is that the container can be any dimension, that is why I would like to have a programmatic way of handling it. Assume that X, instead of being 3D was 4D. The container in this case will contain 3 numbers instead of 2.

Comment: Then you do `X[(slice(None),) + container]`. You can have a tuple for indexing that has any mixture of slices and integers. slice is just a python object [described here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).

Comment: @Arty that is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_selected = X[(slice(None),) + container]`

You can thus index `X` array with any tuple that contains a mixture of `slice`s and integers. `slice` is just a pure python object [described here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). This tuple for indexing should have not more elements than dimensions of `X` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this :

```
x_selected=X[:,container[0],container[1]]
```

I tried with this :

```
A=np.zeros((3,5,7))
A[1,2,:].shape
```

And I got (7,) as the output

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The issue with this approach is that we are assuming that X is always 3D. But in fact, I would require arbitrary dimensions. Assume that X, instead of being 3D was 4D. The container in this case will contain 3 numbers instead of 2. I just modified the question to reflect this, as it was indeed unclear.